# How do I set 301 redirect of multiple urls into a single url?

Tags: nginx, redirect

A `vhost` file in our **NGINX** server handles 301 redirect.

Our current setting is that we redirect a list of urls to its proper url

For example(facility pages to utility pages):

```
location /facility/main-1 {
    return 301 https://$host/utility/main-1/;
}

location /facility/main-2 {
    return 301 https://$host/utility/main-2/;
}
```

But our website is launching a new page with subpages called **/services**

Our **goal** is to redirect both pages under **/facility** and pages under **/utility** to **/services**

Is there such configuration like the one i did below?

```
location /facility/main-1, /utility/main-1/{
    return 301 https://$host/services/main-1/;
}

location /facility/main-2, /utility/main-2/{
    return 301 https://$host/services/main-2/;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This question has the wrong tags. Accurate tagging is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your virtual host do below entry this is for apache/httpd.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

For Nginx do below redirection configuration

```
server {
server_name example.com www.example.com;
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Our line of code is different from yours.. Our list of redirects written above runs on nginx

Comment: Check nginx configuration

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; it redirects to HTTPS

Answer (score 2):

```
location ~* ^/(facility|utility)/main-1/{
    return 301 https://$host/services/main-1/;
}
```